# Add a field to a wave dataset

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics, data-set

I have a defined wave dataset. The object has a new field I would like to use for lenses, dashboards, etc. How do I update the dataset to incorporate this new field?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit old but in case it could you or new users as I think there is an easier way now.

From wave you need to go to data manager, by clicking in the gear icon data manager
[image]

From there you go to dataflow & recipes tab and click in the dataflow
[image]

From there you need to click in the "arrow" > of where you want to add fields, and this will pop up a similar window as when you were importing the fields, if you click in fields you should be able to cherry pick the fields

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is a significant upgrade for users.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the .json file from the dataset and edit the file and you can add the field and upload the worlflow json back

You will find this in data monitor >data flow

Comment: thanks! I have it. Is there documentation on reading, editing it?